# Search in dataGridView with textBox_TextChanged

Tags: c#, winforms, search, datagridview, textbox

I want to do search in dataGridView. I take out my data with:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FileStream f1 = new FileStream("zapis.dat", FileMode.Open);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(f1);
            int а = 0;
            while (f1.Position < f1.Length)
            {
                string data = br.ReadString();
                string sing = br.ReadString();
                string avtor = br.ReadString();
                string zagl = br.ReadString();
                string janr = br.ReadString();
                string ezik = br.ReadString();
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(++а, sing, avtor, zagl, janr, ezik, data);
            }
            f1.Close();
        }
```

for search I use:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter =
string.Format("Name LIKE '{0}%' OR Name LIKE '% {0}%'", textBox1.Text);


    }
```

And when I write in texhtBox it's make me mistake:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'
>
> (... as System.Data.DataTable) returned null.

Can you someone help me? How to do this to works?

Comment: The  `DataSource` is probably not a `DataTable`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to declare DataTable as an object, then ue DefaultView. 
E.g

```
            DataTable dt = tDAL.Search(keyword);
        dgvTalents.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

tDAL is a method in my repo that has a query.